# How are easy-to-spot review audits useful?

Tags: discussion

I know I'm being served an edit review audit when:

1. The review takes several seconds to load
2. The title has nonsense phrase edits

I nearly mechanically Reject for Spam/Vandalism.

I don't really know the usefulness of this audit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are there to catch out robo reviewers.